# JAXB annotation RootElement

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I have the following POJO , and the root element is not showing in the xml file (send over SOAP jax-ws call), can people point out the problem please?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "CATALOGUE")
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD )
public class Catalogue implements Serializable, Comparable<Catalogue>
{

    @XmlTransient
    private Integer catalogueId;

    @XmlElement( name = "COMMENT", required = false, nillable = false )
    private String catalogueComment;

    @XmlElement( name = "VERSION", required = false, nillable = false )
    private String catalogueVersion;

    @XmlElement( name = "VALID_FROM_DTS", required = false, nillable = false )
    private Date catalogueValidFromDts;

    @XmlElement( name = "CREATED_DTS", required = false, nillable = false )
    private Date catalogueCreatedDts;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ITEMLIST")
    @XmlElement(name = "ITEM")
    private List<Item> itemList;

    @XmlTransient
    private Integer catalogueLifecyclePhase;

    @XmlTransient
    private Integer ownerId;
```

the xml file looks like

```
            <COMMENT>LK</COMMENT>
            <VERSION>4</VERSION>
            <VALID_FROM_DTS>1990-01-25T00:00:00Z</VALID_FROM_DTS>
            <CREATED_DTS>2012-05-14T15:49:38.655+01:00</CREATED_DTS>
            <ITEMLIST>
                <ITEM>
                    <NAME>Adult Period Pass Corsham</NAME>
                    <DESC>1 week</DESC>
                    <SKU>ACT-38</SKU>
                    <PRICE>15</PRICE>
                    <CATEGORIES>
                        <CATEGORY>
                            <CategoryName>Product</CategoryName>
                            <CategoryDate>1 week</CategoryDate>
                            <CategorySortOrder>0</CategorySortOrder>
                        </CATEGORY>
                        <CATEGORY>
                            <CategoryName>Product Type</CategoryName>
                            <CategoryDate>Coach</CategoryDate>
                            <CategorySortOrder>0</CategorySortOrder>
                        </CATEGORY>
                        .....................
```

i would expecting something like

```
         <CATALOGUE>     <-----------missing!!!
            <COMMENT>LK</COMMENT>
            <VERSION>4</VERSION>
            <VALID_FROM_DTS>1990-01-25T00:00:00Z</VALID_FROM_DTS>
            <CREATED_DTS>2012-05-14T15:49:38.655+01:00</CREATED_DTS>
            <ITEMLIST>
                <ITEM>
                    <NAME>Adult Period Pass Corsham</NAME>
                    <DESC>1 week</DESC>
                    <SKU>ACT-38</SKU>
                    <PRICE>15</PRICE>
                    <CATEGORIES>
                        <CATEGORY>
                            <CategoryName>Product</CategoryName>
                            <CategoryDate>1 week</CategoryDate>
                            <CategorySortOrder>0</CategorySortOrder>
                        </CATEGORY>
                        <CATEGORY>
                            <CategoryName>Product Type</CategoryName>
                            <CategoryDate>Coach</CategoryDate>
                            <CategorySortOrder>0</CategorySortOrder>
                        </CATEGORY>
                        .....................
                 </CATALOGUE>
```

The Code used to Return the Object is

```
@Stateless
@Remote
@WebService
public class CatalogueManagerSoapService
{

    public CatalogueManagerSoapService()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @EJB
    private SOAPExportService userService;


    @WebMethod
    public Catalogue getLatestCatalogue(
            String username,
            String password,
            String catalogueName ) throws Exception
    { 
          Catalogue c = CatManager.getCatalogue();    
          return c;  
        }  

}
```

Comment: Post the code you are using to serialize the object to XML.

Comment: added new code to the origional question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer my Own question

this is what the JAX-WS (JRS181) default implementation for @WebResult

```
@Retention(value=RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD})
public @interface WebResult {

    String name() default "return";
    String targetNamespace() default "";
    boolean header() default false;
    String partName() default "";
}
```

as you can see "return" is by default. 
change to @WebResult( name = "CATALOGUE") solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need a package-info.java file, try something like this:

```
@XmlSchema(namespace = "<your namespace>",

xmlns = @XmlNs(prefix = "<your prefix>", namespaceURI = "<your namespace>"),

elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED

)
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlAccessorOrder(XmlAccessOrder.UNDEFINED)
package your.package.name;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessOrder;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorOrder;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNs;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

just put it in the root of your package, edit as needed and generate the xsd again. Should be ok.

Comment: thanks. type must be FIELD I guess @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) because I am using the class fields as annotated target, will try the rest.